How do you calculate switching power?
I am seeing what seems to me to be conflicting answers on how to do a basic calculation of switching power and I want to make sure I am doing it right. My understanding is this:
Take a clock signal with frequency f and load capacitance C.
The capacitor charges up to Q (and then discharges down to zero) once per clock cycle.
Q = C*V
Energy = QV = CVV = CV^2
Power = Energy/s = C*V^2 * f
Now, as for the switching factor (or activity factor or alpha), that is between 0 and 1.
For a clock, which switches once every period of the frequency, the switching factor = 1.
So switching power = C*V^2 * f
But for an inverter, the probability of switching is 1/2, so switching factor = 0.5
Which would make switching power = 0.5 * C*V^2 * f
And for some other device with a switching probability of 0.25, switching power = 0.25 CV^2 * f
And so on.
Here are some examples of which contradict my understanding:
example1
example2
example3
example4
example5
Examples 1 and 2 seem to say that the switching power is at most 0.5CV^2*f, and you multiply that term by the switching factor, but the 0.5 is always included.
Examples 3, 4 and 5 don't seem to include the 0.5 factor, which aligns with my understanding.
If my understanding is incorrect, can anyone explain to me what I am getting wrong?

The energy put into a capacitor to lift it to \$V\$ volts from zero volts is \$\frac{1}{2} CV^2\$.
The energy taken from the DC power supply to charge the capacitor is \$CV^2\$ but, that includes the resistance of the driving circuit that charges the capacitor (it also takes the same amount of energy but converts that to unusable heat).
Because all the energy ends up being converted to heat, the power consumed is \$CV^2\times f\$.
For the power supply and the heat dissipated in your device, the duty cycle is irrelevant.
